# How to use TARGETDIR in visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++

Currently the path inside my code is hardcoded. I want to make it dynamic, base on the users selected installation path.

How can I use `TARGETDIR` inside my code here:

```
      SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {0};
  info.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
  info.fMask  = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
  info.lpFile = _T("C:\\PROGRA~1\\APPY\\IECapt.exe");
  info.lpParameters = full;
  info.nShow = SW_HIDE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TARGETDIR is the path to the directory where you .EXE file is linked. And it's only available at compile time. You want to get the installation directory, so TARGETDIR is not useful.

[`GetModuleFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms683197.aspx) gives you the path, where your .EXE has been loaded.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this, but I'm out of votes. This is the correct answer.

Comment: You only get 30 votes a day, which you can use either to up or down vote questions and answers. I already used all of mine earlier today, so I can't give your answer an up-vote. I was just commenting that this is the correct solution, in lieu of leaving an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion......
You can use one button and in the OnButonClick() function add the below codes with your other codes..........

```
    CFileDialog m_IDFile(TRUE);
    m_IDFile1.m_ofn.lpstrInitialDir=L"C:\\PROGRA~1\\APPY\\";
    if(m_IDFile1.DoModal()==IDOK)
    m_cFileName=m_IDFile1.GetPathName();
    info.lpFile = _T(m_cFileName);
```

Comment: You kept the hard-coded path to the Program Files folder. Don't **ever** do that.